# Ncurses User Pointer

Tags: c++, ncurses, void-pointers

I'm trying to learn ncurses, and I'm reading the terrific guide [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), but the example at [user pointers](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html#MENUUSERPTR) does not compile. I get this error when I try to compile.

`menu.cpp: In function 'int main()':`

`menu.cpp:44: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(char*)' to 'void*'`

`menu.cpp:44: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'int set_item_userptr(ITEM*, void*)'`

`menu.cpp:70: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'void (*)(char*)'`

Also, you probably need to add cstdlib and cstring for that to compile with strlen and calloc.

I don't know much about void pointers, so some help fixing the example would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the manual page:

```
#include <menu.h>
int set_item_userptr(ITEM *item, void *userptr);
void *item_userptr(const ITEM *item);
```

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Every  menu  item has a field that can be used to hold application-specific data (that is, the menu-driver  code  leaves  it  alone).   These functions get and set that field.

`userptr` is user-specific data that you should supply to `set_item_userptr()`.  If you don't want to supply any data, you should supply `NULL`.  Looks like you are calling `set_item_userptr()` with a pointer to a function as its second argument.  It is not guaranteed that you can convert a function-pointer to `void *` and back portably, either in C or in C++ (C++ requires a cast when converting a `void *` to any other pointer type).  Without knowing what you are trying to do, if you really need to pass a function pointer, you should cast it to the appropriate type:

```
int ret = set_item_userptr(item, reinterpret_cast<void *>(ptr));
void (*pf)(char*);
pf = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(char *)>(item_userptr(item));
```

but it's not guaranteed to work.  You should do something else, like having a `struct` that contains the function pointer, and passing a pointer to the `struct` to `set_item_userptr()`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make a menu that will execute some function when I hit enter on the selection.

Comment: @Reti: I don't know curses, but I am guessing there should be a better way of doing what you want to do than to cast a function pointer to `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a C++ compiler, so you will need to do:

```
    set_item_userptr(my_items[i], (void *)func);
```

and again,

```
    p = (void*)item_userptr(cur);
```

Comment: Two comments.  1 - I'd recommend reinterpret_cast<> as better style then C style casts.  2 - line 70 is the reverse cast so the cast should be `p = reinterpret_cast<void (*)(char *)>(item_userptr(cur));`

Comment: Why `reinterpret_cast` if `static_cast` to `void*` and back is fine?

Comment: @gf - static_cast will not convert between `void *` and `void (*)(char *)`.  Trying static_cast on g++ 4.2.1 gives `invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘void (*)(char*)’`.

Comment: @*Actually, I prefer the C-style casts -- let the compiler choose the best fit -- in such cases (over `reinterpret_cast`s).

Comment: @R Samuel: Ah, i didn't know that the handling was different for function pointers.